# Request feedback/clarification on a rejected edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

My [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27326462) (to add in a missing code snippet) was rejected with the following reasons. I am providing some context/explanation, but I would like some feedback/clarification, as this is only my second attempt at editing.

- First reason/reviewer:

  > "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

  - *The intent of my edit was to make the answer "more accurate"*, as (without the missing code snippet) **the answer was not completely accurate** (in fact, it caused an error).
- Second reason/reviewer:

  > "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

  - This reason is a little more accurate/helpful (IMO) than the first reason, but my arguments against "makes no sense as an edit" / "should have been written as a comment or an answer":

    - The author's intention seemed to be to include the snippet:

      - The sentence includes the ":" where the snippet should have gone (at the end/after the ":")

      > Add this to the plugins array in the karma.conf.js file :

      - The next sentence refers back to performing the missing action (adding the code snippet to the karma.conf.js file) (as if they intended to include it) (emphasis, mine):

      > **This** gives you the spec reporter, [...]
    - Without it, the answer isn't fully accurate (but has a fair amount of upvotes: 30), so waiting on the author to notice/care about addressing a comment (their answer is over a year old) doesn't make sense to me.
    - It also doesn't make sense to add another answer that is basically an edit to the answer in question here.

#### Questions

- Should my "reason for edit" have been more clear (might it have reasonably impacted the reviewers decisions in this case)?

> added in seemingly intended but omitted code snippet

- Generally speaking, how much do reviewers factor in the "reason for edit" in their decision to approve/reject?
- Is the "resolution" ("It should have been written as a comment or an answer") in a situation like this really the way it should be handled? *(I have added a comment in the meanwhile)*

Comment: I would have rejected the edit because you added some code to an answer where it is unclear where the code is coming from. Use edits to format posts, fix typos, add formatting, but not to add new code/content to it. Also note, that the answer got 30 upvotes without the snipped, so it is (from a reviewer perspective) questionable how relevant it is.

Comment: Derek's rejection reason... I can't agree with, jason's however..., reviewers aren't expected to have domain knowledge and it's not clear where the code came from or if it's correct. Leaving a comment (as you have done) IMO is the better option (over suggesting an edit for that). Re: your questions, 1) Yes, give them _all_ the information they need to make an _informed_ decision, 2) unanswerable, depends on the reviewer, I do read them, including rejecting edits if the edit is only a minor improvement and the reason is just garbage, 3) IMO... yes, others likely will disagree

Comment: IMO this should have been a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543241/angular-6-unit-tests-an-error-was-thrown-in-afterall-nreferenceerror-cant-fin/56276277#comment113609750_56276277) and is inappropriate as an edit.

Comment: Thank you, this is good feedback.  I think I'm ready to answer my question.
Would the following be appropriate?
Generally speaking, 
* Making an edit that potentially changes the intent (and not simply the appearance, i.e., fixing formatting, typos, etc.) of another person's question/answer is not a good practice
* Making an edit that would require a reviewer to potentially have domain knowledge is not a good practice.  
For both of these situations, leaving a comment on the answer/question would be the best way to handle it.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments you've *added* code to the post as an edit - this is covered by standard "when to edit code" which I picked as duplicate: "Make the code do something different than what the answer says it does" . While I agree that something is missing in the answer at that line it is hard to say if your change is correct or not unless one is proficient with that particular library. Note that author "Last seen Oct 3 at 22:34" so commenting has good chance to succeed in getting it fixed.

Comment: @GreggL sounds mostly accurate, for cases where it does appear to change intent, or where domain knowledge is needed however you can _provide_ it. If there's a comment from the OP with more information and you're adding it in to the post, say so and provide a link to it in your edit message. If you're adding an excerpt from documentation, provide a link to it in your edit message. And lastly, don't make an edit that only fixes one thing, unless that's all there is to fix, you should be fixing everything you can within the post.